# Use TracI to simulate V2V

Tags: omnet++

I am using omnet and sumo to simulate V2V,when I run the examples in omnetpp, the recommended way is to use sumo-launchd.py but I need to use TracI so that I can combine sumo with unity3D.So is there any way use traci instead of sumo-launchd.py?
Besides,as I am new to use omnet++,the complicated codes and modules make me stressed,it will be better if I can find some projects to run.